# How to parse out all columns out of a sql using regular expression?

Tags: java, sql, regex

I want to parse out all the columns out of a sql using regular expression, but no idea about parsing sql coming with functions.Like :

```
 SELECT
   NVL(SUM(MISSIONNO), 0) DISTCNT, COUNT(DISTINCT(USERID)) USERIDCNT
  FROM EVTSUPPLYHIST
 WHERE EVTCODE = #evtCode#
   AND EVTNO = #evtNo#
   AND GIFTCODE = #giftCode#
   AND SUPPLYDT BETWEEN TO_DATE(#startDate#, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') 
   AND TO_DATE(#endDate#, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

For this sql above , right results should be DISTCNT and USERIDCNT, as you might guess it's not pure and clean sql, but ibatis-based paremetered sql.Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think there's a magic bullet, SQL is a language, parsing languages requires writing parsers. I'm sure if you search around, you'll find an SQL parser written in Java. Note that since SQL isn't a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), you will **not** be able to reliably parse it using regular expressions.

Comment: use sql parser instead of regexp

Comment: It's not so easy. And you can't do that only with regex because of many nested parentheses.

Comment: Maybe as a rough first approximation you can look for words preceding a comma or preceding a 'FROM' (after removing new lines from the query) consisting of `[a-zA-Z_]`?  If the query is `SELECT COUNT(USERID) FROM USER_INFO` what do you want to return? I suppose you could also allow for multiple words in a column name if it was surrounded by back ticks ("SELECT `user id` FROM ..")

Comment: I'll do some research on sql parser, but unfortunately ,my sql is not pure and clean sql, that is it's parametered sql in a flavor of ibatis, not sure if it's ok with that, it's worth a research. I've reedited the thread and paste the full sql. thanks

Comment: Finally I selected General SQL Parser for Java,it's official website offers many samples which makes learning so easy. And it meets my requirements even if when the sql conatins ibatis parameter mark '#'  except it is commercial.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using one of the many SQL expression parsers, like [zql](http://zql.sourceforge.net/). From their documentation I see, that they create a java objects from an SQL expression and it should be quite trivial to get the column names from that datastructure.

Comment: I tried zql, but seems like it's not well-documented, then I gave up.

Comment: They provide some good examples, took me a few minutes to parse a sql query string, but - it will not read your *special* sql dialect. (unrecognized function `NVL`) One would have to adapt the JavaCC input files

Answer (score 1):

If you can wait after you've executed the query you may get all the informations very easily from the returned ResultSet.

```
ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
int colCount = meta.getColumnCount();

for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
  String colName = meta.getColumnName(i + 1);
}
```

Comment: If it's executed through jdbc, it's totally right. But my scenario is I need get the information without jdbc execution. I'm working on a code generation tool which can generate vo according to the sql.